# API event error - Event Definition Key not found

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, journeybuilder

I have 3 journeys and when trying to connect from my website to the journey I receive the following error:

```json
{
    "message": "EventDefinitionKey 'APIEvent-1843bf88-e9aa-f083-95cf-e49409ff3ea0' not found",
    "errorcode": 10000,
    "documentation": ""
}
```

Anyone know why I receive this error?

Comment: check your API entry event definition key, if its matching or not. Check the version of your journey and key should be of the running version.

Comment: The API entry event is correct & matches, there is only 1 version.

Comment: @Kate Please mark my answer as accepted if it helped resolve your problem, so others can easily see this has been answered correctly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If this EventDefinitionKey is definitely correct, this issue usually occurs if the "Installed Package" (API credentials) doesn't have the correct access rights to the Business Unit your journey is implemented in.

Try checking this by navigating go *Administration -> Account -> Installed Packages* and clicking on the package you used for the API Integration. Then check the information under *Components -> API Integration -> Business Unit* (see the screenshot below [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laVsS.png)).

In addition to that, also pass the MID of your Business Unit in the `account_id` parameter when requesting the access token ([accessToken request documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/access-token-s2s.htm)). That should solve the problem.

[image: Managed Package Administration, Package Details (Business Unit)]

Comment: Additionally, besides the business unit access, the API Package needs permission access to Email > Read.

Comment: @MilanSimic thats correct, however you should receive a different error message in that case.